# How I want to split my table when I use long table and page break it didn't work. I want to split it after 15 citation

Tags: tables, longtable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\caption{Relevant heuristic techniques}\label{title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}|}
 \hline
 Techniques         &  Aim & Distinctive attributes &  Limitations \\ %\midrule
 \hline
Hybrid technique (GA and WDO) \cite{8}&  Minimization of cost and PAR& HEMS model is considered with DER and energy storage system& User comfort is ignored\\
\hline
EA \cite{9} & Cost reduction  & Energy optimization in residential area, commercial area, and industrial & System complexity is enhanced     \\
 \hline
 BPSO \cite{10}& Primary steps of BPSO, its variant, and application& Working of BPSO in complex environment, its improved steps, and merging with other techniques discussed& Practical implementation not addressed\\
\hline
BPSO \cite{11}& Cost minimization & Scheduling Energy consumption patterns of appliances, its simplicity & PAR is not addressed and user comfort is ignored\\
\hline
 GA \cite{12}& Cost reduction and user comfort& User comfort by optimizing energy consumption behavior of residential, commercial and industrial area  & System deals with large number of appliances in multiple sector which increases system complexity \\
\hline
GA, BPSO, ACO \cite{13}& Cost and PAR reduction & HEMC schedules the appliances by considering user satisfaction and RESs integration& Computational time and system complexity is increased\\
\hline
GA \cite{14}& User comfort and cost reduction & Optimizes energy consumption behavior with RESs incorporation &  Practical implementation increases system complexity\\
\hline
 Hybrid(LP and BPSO) \cite{15}& Cost reduction and user comfort maximization  & Thermostatically and interruptible appliances are considered with load ahead pricing model & PAR is not considered \\
\hline 
\pagebreak
FP \cite{16} & Electricity cost reduction  & Cost efficient model with DES and practical implementation of the model proposed   & PAR and User comfort are not taken into account\\
\hline
GA \cite{17}& Cost and PAR reduction& For efficient cost model time slots are divided& System complexity and computational time enhances\\
\hline\\
HSA \cite{18}& Basic concept of HSA, its structure, and applications& Improved and Hybrid HSA with application & Real time implementation  is not considered   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear (partly as it has no words in the question, just a code block) also you have tagged it longtable but the code you show does not use that package.

Comment: are your `\cite` keys really numbers in your real document? That would be very odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the the last but one row you have after `hline` command `\\`- Remove it.

For your table I would change page layout (for example by use of `geometry` package), use `tabularx` environment for a table ans `cellspace` for more space around contents of cells:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, cellspace, multirow, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

    \usepackage[showframe,margin=25mm]{geometry}% <-- added

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
   % \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
    \caption{Relevant heuristic techniques}\label{title}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | C | C | C|}
```

With this changes I obtain:

[image]

Further improvements of table looks you can achieve with use rules from package `booktabs`. In this case you don't need `cellspace` package for more vertical space around cells' contents. This now can be accomplished with `\addlinespace`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
%    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
%\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

    \usepackage[showframe,margin=25mm]{geometry}% <-- added

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
   % \setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
    \caption{Relevant heuristic techniques}\label{title}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\raggedright}p{1in}  L  L  L}
     \toprule
     Techniques         &  Aim & Distinctive attributes &  Limitations \\ %\midrule
     \midrule
    Hybrid technique (GA and WDO) \cite{8}&  Minimization of cost and PAR& HEMS model is considered with DER and energy storage system& User comfort is ignored\\
\addlinespace
    EA \cite{9} & Cost reduction  & Energy optimization in residential area, commercial area, and industrial & System complexity is enhanced     \\
\addlinespace
     BPSO \cite{10}& Primary steps of BPSO, its variant, and application& Working of BPSO in complex environment, its improved steps, and merging with other techniques discussed& Practical implementation not addressed\\
\addlinespace
    BPSO \cite{11}& Cost minimization & Scheduling Energy consumption patterns of appliances, its simplicity & PAR is not addressed and user comfort is ignored\\
\addlinespace
     GA \cite{12}& Cost reduction and user comfort& User comfort by optimizing energy consumption behavior of residential, commercial and industrial area  & System deals with large number of appliances in multiple sector which increases system complexity \\
\addlinespace
    GA, BPSO, ACO \cite{13}& Cost and PAR reduction & HEMC schedules the appliances by considering user satisfaction and RESs integration& Computational time and system complexity is increased\\
\addlinespace
    GA \cite{14}& User comfort and cost reduction & Optimizes energy consumption behavior with RESs incorporation &  Practical implementation increases system complexity\\
\addlinespace
     Hybrid(LP and BPSO) \cite{15}& Cost reduction and user comfort maximization  & Thermostatically and interruptible appliances are considered with load ahead pricing model & PAR is not considered \\
\addlinespace
%    \pagebreak
    FP \cite{16} & Electricity cost reduction  & Cost efficient model with DES and practical implementation of the model proposed   & PAR and User comfort are not taken into account\\
\addlinespace
    GA \cite{17}& Cost and PAR reduction& For efficient cost model time slots are divided& System complexity and computational time enhances\\
\addlinespace
    HSA \cite{18}& Basic concept of HSA, its structure, and applications& Improved and Hybrid HSA with application & Real time implementation  is not considered   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

IN both solution is not considered to use `longtable`, since with selected page layout this is not necessary. Let me noted, use `\pagebreak` inside `table` environment nor in `longtable` doesn't work as might you expected. I delete it in both showed examples.

Also from `table*` one can conclude, that your document has two columns, but this is not set in your MWE. With `table*` options for table positioning hasn't sence since it can be only on top of (the next) page.

If you really need `longtable`, than you can not enclose it in `table` environment` IN case of two columns document this cause further complications, since you need to discontinue two columns (what push table again on the top of the next page)

**Addendum:**
For some reason you demand that table, which can be fit in one page, had to be split into pages (at prescribed row). This can be eventually done, if you put table direct in document and for caption use `caption` package or `capt-of` and manually divide table in two table ... or use `longtable` (see MWE below) and hope that it will divide at desired row (which can happen, if on the page is enough space for the first part of table).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}% for dummy text

\usepackage[showframe,margin=25mm]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{>{\RaggedRight}p{1in}
             *{3}{>{\RaggedRight}p{\dimexpr0.333\linewidth-0.333in-2.667\tabcolsep}}
                 }
\caption{Relevant heuristic techniques}
    \label{title}\\
 \toprule
 Techniques         &  Aim & Distinctive attributes &  Limitations \\
 \midrule
 \endfirsthead
\caption{Relevant heuristic techniques (cont.)}
    \label{title}\\
 \toprule
 Techniques         &  Aim & Distinctive attributes &  Limitations \\
 \midrule
 \endhead
 \midrule[0.8pt]
 \multicolumn{4}{r}{continue on the next page}
 \endfoot
 \bottomrule
 \endlastfoot
 % table content
Hybrid technique (GA and WDO) \cite{8}&  Minimization of cost and PAR& HEMS model is considered with DER and energy storage system& User comfort is ignored\\
\addlinespace
EA \cite{9} & Cost reduction  & Energy optimization in residential area, commercial area, and industrial & System complexity is enhanced     \\
\addlinespace
 BPSO \cite{10}& Primary steps of BPSO, its variant, and application& Working of BPSO in complex environment, its improved steps, and merging with other techniques discussed& Practical implementation not addressed\\
\addlinespace
BPSO \cite{11}& Cost minimization & Scheduling Energy consumption patterns of appliances, its simplicity & PAR is not addressed and user comfort is ignored\\
\addlinespace
 GA \cite{12}& Cost reduction and user comfort& User comfort by optimizing energy consumption behavior of residential, commercial and industrial area  & System deals with large number of appliances in multiple sector which increases system complexity \\
\addlinespace
GA, BPSO, ACO \cite{13}& Cost and PAR reduction & HEMC schedules the appliances by considering user satisfaction and RESs integration& Computational time and system complexity is increased\\
\addlinespace
GA \cite{14}& User comfort and cost reduction & Optimizes energy consumption behavior with RESs incorporation &  Practical implementation increases system complexity\\
\addlinespace
 Hybrid(LP and BPSO) \cite{15}& Cost reduction and user comfort maximization  & Thermostatically and interruptible appliances are considered with load ahead pricing model & PAR is not considered \\
\addlinespace
%\pagebreak
FP \cite{16} & Electricity cost reduction  & Cost efficient model with DES and practical implementation of the model proposed   & PAR and User comfort are not taken into account\\
\addlinespace
GA \cite{17}& Cost and PAR reduction& For efficient cost model time slots are divided& System complexity and computational time enhances\\
\addlinespace
HSA \cite{18}& Basic concept of HSA, its structure, and applications& Improved and Hybrid HSA with application & Real time implementation  is not considered   \\
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

In above MWE is considered *Mico* comment. This code gives:

[image]

Comment: Dear answered! I understand your answer but what I really need is to shift the table from row 8 to the next and I'm able to do that this is a problem I'm facing. Thank you

Comment: well, if you able to do this, what is the question?

Comment: But it is not shifting on the next page this is the problem which I'm trying.

Comment: please, be more precise. in comment above you say , that this you can do. Sorry, but I'm confused now.

Comment: @Mico, considered in addendum to my answer. Thank you for pointing this improvement.

Comment: @Mico, I see that today is not my day for math (and width calculation) :-( Corrected.