# How to get a wide longtable with short paragraphs in its cells and can be extended on multiple landscape pages?

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I am working with a descriptive table of a literature review on an Excel sheet, which I hope will be rearranged with a neat style in latex later to be a wide long table with short paragraphs in its cell which can be extended on multiple landscape pages as in the associated image below.The current table which I got so far, it is not organized nor centered and breaks on pages randomly. See the the associated image, below. 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\afterpage{
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}\centering
\begin{longtable}[!htp]{| p{.50\textwidth} | p{.15\textwidth} |p{.15\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.45\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.30\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}  & \textbf{Column 3}  & \textbf{Column 4} & \textbf{Column 5} & \textbf{Column 6}  & \textbf{Column 7}  & \textbf{Column 8}
\\ \hline
\lipsum[1-1]. & 20 & 2014 & Journal  & \lipsum[1]. & France & \lipsum[1] & 230.
\\ \hline
\lipsum[1]. & 10 & 2015 & Confernce & \lipsum[1]. & UK &  \lipsum[1]  & 120.
\\ \hline

\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
label{tab:mylongtable}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
    \pagestyle{plain}
 \clearpage
  }
%\end{table}

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```

Comment: what you try so far? how the table should looks? welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't share the code, because I am still new, who doesn't have 10 reputations so I have only only one link to post in the question (that is why I linked an image only). I am trying to get a wide table with verbatim, which can extend to several landscape pages and looks neat (centered and continuously flows through the pages).

Comment: (i) without see your table is very difficult to help you, (ii) even with your reputation it is possible to load in question minimal working example (mwe), a code for complete small document, which we can copy and test), (iii) without mwe  only general advice is possible: search here for similar question and on basis of their answer try to construct your table.

Comment: for example, for start see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368074/. for landscape orientation you need to add `\usepackage{pdflscape}` in document preamble and then table set between `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}`. in this orientation `longtable` can occupy many pages ...

Comment: you should provide a code example it's very hard to comment on an image. However the page breaking is not "random" it happens between rows (never within a row) so the page breaking you show in the image is as expected.

Comment: Thanks Zarko and David, I have added the code. Hope this can be more clear than the image. I would like to get a wide long table which can go continuously in the middle of multiple landscape pages. Your suggestions and modifications to the code are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your table is huge
- through columns widths you define table width equal `(.50+.15+.15+.15+.45+.15+.30+.15)*\textwidth=2*\textwidth`, consequently table spill-out on pages right sides
- instead of `longtable` i suggest to use `ltablex` to which you prescribe table width
- for better fit text in cells the reduction of font size is necessary, for example to `\small`
- to reduce width of `c` type columns see if use of the `\thead{...}` from `makecell` package is fine to you

  (i assumed, that cells in columns 2, 3, 4, 6 and 8 has only short, one line content; if this assumption is wrong, than you need to convert it to `X` type columns and determine their relative width)
- more "profesional look is obtain with removing of verticaql linens and use rules for horizontal lines from package `booktabs` (if you not liked such design, you ca returno vertical lines and replaces `rules` with `hlines`
- note: table can broke between pages only between rows

*mwe*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
% \usepackage{pdflscape} % alternative to lscape
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, ltablex}
% \keepXColumns % preserve X column formatting

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\lipsum[1-5]

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
‎\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X l l l
                    >{\hsize=0.35\hsize}X l
                    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X l
                              @{}}
\caption{Your caption here}
\label{tab:mylongtable}         \\
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Column 1}     & \thead[l]{Column\\ 2} & \thead[l]{Column\\ 3} &
\thead[l]{Column\\ 4}   & \thead[l]{Column 5}   & \thead[l]{Column\\ 6} &
\thead[l]{Column 7}     & \thead[l]{Column\\ 8} \\ 
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
%%%%
\caption{Your caption here (cont.)}
\label{tab:mylongtable}         \\
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Column 1}     & \thead[l]{Column\\ 2} & \thead[l]{Column\\ 3} &
\thead[l]{Column\\ 4}   & \thead[l]{Column 5}   & \thead[l]{Column\\ 6} &
\thead[l]{Column 7}     & \thead[l]{Column\\ 8} \\ 
    \midrule
\endhead
%%%%
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
%%%%
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%% table content
\lipsum[11]             & 20                    & 2014                  &
Journal                 & \lipsum[11]           & France                &
\lipsum[11]             & 230                   \\ \midrule
\lipsum[11]             & 10                    & 2015                  &
Conference              & \lipsum[11]           & UK                    &
\lipsum[11]             & 120                   \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Zarko, this works for me, your help is appreciated

Comment: @mhdella, i slightly improve my *mwe* and explanation regarding `c` columns. happy tex-ing!

Comment: Got it Zarko, thanx, I really appreciate your cooperation.